# click to copy paragraph content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was tried to copy paragraph content when I click on it,
I wrote this code but it's not working correctly

here the code:

```
$('p').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $temp.val($(this).html()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
});
```

Comment: I think the element must be visible on the page to to get `$temp.val($(this).html()).select();` to work.

Comment: Instead of .html() you can use .text()

Comment: Just add `$("body").append($temp);` before you call the `$temp.val($(this).html()).select();` and you're golden. https://jsfiddle.net/asek26nw/

Comment: You can change .html() to .text()

Comment: Take a look here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange

Answer (score 1):

Here, this adds a click listener and filters on P tags. When clicked it will copy to clipboard.

```js
const copyElement = (e) => {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    selection.removeAllRanges();
  }
  
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(e);
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');
};

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('p')) {
    copyElement(e.target);
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Testing</p>
<div>No copy</div>
<p>Test2</p>
```

Comment: i love it works great... I am trying to add a copy image on click.... i replaced 'p' with 'img' in 2nd to last line and it select the image with an outline but my clipboard doesnt copy the  image, its just blank... any tweaks you can add for images as well?